# Convert type(String) to pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string
say

```
type(abc)
>>str
```

i want to convert it into pandas.core.series.Series.

i came across in pandas documentation that there is a code

```
pd.to_string()
```

which converts pandas series to string, but i want the opposit of it.
is there any function/code to do it?

Comment: Please explain what you want the Series to look like.  If you have a string `"abc"`, what do you want the Series you get from it to contain?

Comment: @my string has a number. say 123.

Comment: Why do you want to make a single number into a Series?  A Series is a container type for holding a sequence of values.

Comment: @BrenBarn  this is just a part of my whole code,which requires me to work with pandas series, and i'm running it in a loop and was getting error due to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an implementation for casting a string to a series -

```
>>> abc = 'some string'
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> abc_series = pd.Series(abc)
>>> type(abc_series)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your string a representation of a series like `"0    1\nName: My_Series, dtype: int64"`? You didn't clarify. If this is what you meant I've found no direct way of doing this, though this seems to be close enough:

```
import io

a = "0    1\nName: My_Series, dtype: int64"
_f = io.StringIO('\n'.join(a.split('\n')[:-1]))
pd.read_csv(_f, header=None, index_col=0, sep=r'\s+')
```

Comment: Instead of manually removing the last line, you could just set `skipfooter=1` (as well as `engine='python'` to avoid a `ParserWarning`).

Comment: Or you can use `.rpartition()` to make it easier, plus you can extract the info from the footer: `body, _, footer = a.rpartition('\n'); name, dtype = re.match(r'^Name: (.*), dtype: (.*)$', footer).groups(); _f = io.StringIO(body); pd.read_csv(..., names=[name], dtype=dtype)`